# Converting decimal miles from Google Maps to int32

Tags: javascript, asp.net, math, substring

I have an Asp.net text box that is being auto populated by javascript using Google Maps Api.
The text in the textbox can show any amount of miles from 40.2 - 1,634 mi ect.

I need to take the text from the text box and put it into an int to be stored in the DB.

So really I need a couple things to happen. The text always shows as "40.2 mi" (without the quotes) and what I need is just a round number. or Int. like "40" or "1634".

So I can store this in my DB table. I've tried Substring and Math.Round. But I keep getting exceptions. My most recent attempt is this:

```
        string miles = txtEstDistance.Text;
        miles.Substring(0, miles.IndexOf('.') > 0 ? miles.IndexOf('.') : miles.Length);

        int oDistanceMiles = Convert.ToInt32(miles);
```

And the exception I'm getting is:"Input string was not in a correct format." for this line of code:

int oDistanceMiles = Convert.ToInt32(miles);

I'm lost. .Net 4.0 C#

Comment: Probably need to get rid of the "mi" suffix, if that's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you get rid of the " mi" first, and treat the rest as a float? Then you can use the Math.Round to round to a whole number and convert that to an int.

If I'm right, the NumberStyles.Float enum will automatically clean up leading or trailing white space. Of course, you can also use string.Trim()

```
var miles = txtEstDistance.Text;

miles = miles.Substring(0, miles.IndexOf("mi"));

float tmpdistance;
var success = float.TryParse(miles, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tmpdistance);

if (success)
{
    var distance = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(tmpdistance, 0));

    // or

    distance = (int) Math.Round(tmpdistance, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a dot, you have a string like `40 mi`, so you need to use the space.

```
miles.Substring(0, miles.IndexOf('.') > 0 ? miles.IndexOf('.') : miles.IndexOf(' '));
```